# install laravel 5 error composer.phar on line 23

Tags: error-handling, installation, composer-php, laravel-5

create laravel 5 project:
composer create-project laravel/laravel wifi dev-develop --prefer-dist

Error:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message 'phar "/usr/local/bin/composer.phar" has a broken signature' in /usr/local/bin/composer.phar:23
Stack trace:

> 0 /usr/local/bin/composer.phar(23): Phar::mapPhar('composer.phar')
>
> 1 {main}
>     thrown in /usr/local/bin/composer.phar on line 23

Answer (score 1):

This is a composer problem not a Laravel one.

Your composer.phar may be corrupted try to re-download the composer using the instructions from [here](https://getcomposer.org/download/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a composer problem, try:

```
Sudo su

composer self-update
```